# How to associate a generated file with a Django model

Tags: django, file

I want to create a file and associate it with the `FileField` of my model. Here's my simplified attempt:

```
#instantiate my form with the POST data
form = CSSForm(request.POST)
#generate a css object from a ModelForm
css = form.save(commit=False)
#generate some css:
css_string = "body {color: #a9f;}"
#create a css file:
filename = "myfile.css"
#try to write the file and associate it with the model
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    df = File(f) #create django File object
    df.write(css_string)
    css.css_file = df
css.save()
```

The call to `save()` throws a `"seek of closed file"` exception. If I move the `save()` to the `with` block, it produces an unsupported operation `"read"`. At the moment, the files are being created in my media directory, but are empty. If I just render the `css_string` with the `HttpResponse` then I see the expected css.

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#the-file-object) don't seem to have an example on how to link a generated file and a database field. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django `FileField` would either be a `django.core.files.File`, which is a file instance or `django.core.files.base.ContentFile`, which takes a string as parameter and compose a `ContentFile`. Since you already had the file content as a string, sounds like `ContentFile` is the way to go(I couldn't test it but it should work):

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

# create an in memory instance
css = form.save(commit=False)
# file content as string
css_string = "body {color: #a9f;}"
# create ContentFile instance
css_file = ContentFile(css_string)
# assign the file to the FileField
css.css_file.save('myfile.css', css_file)
css.save()
```

Check django doc about [FileField details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile).